# DataGridView's Button Click Event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a *DataGridView* which I populate using *DataAdapter + DataTable*.
I used the following code to create a *button*:

```
 #region CreatGridButtons
            //Botão DELETAR
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btn_deletar = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btn_deletar.HeaderText = "DELETAR";
            btn_deletar.Text = "DELETAR";
            btn_deletar.Name = "btn_apagar";
            btn_deletar.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; 

            DataGridViewButtonColumn btn_editar = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btn_editar.HeaderText = "EDITAR";
            btn_editar.Text = "EDITAR";
            btn_editar.Name = "btn_editar";
            btn_editar.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; 

            dgv_tipo_despesas.Columns.Add(btn_deletar);
            dgv_tipo_despesas.Columns.Add(btn_editar);

            #endregion
```

Also, I tried this:

```
private void dgv_tipo_despesas_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || dgv_tipo_despesas.cell) return;
    {
         ///ExecuteSomeCode
    }
  }
```

But it gave me this error: * Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I need to execute some code when these buttons are *pressed/clicked*. I have already accomplished this goal by using the following *events*:

- *DataGridView_CellClick*
- *DataGridView_CellContentClick*

They both work fine, but... It is also fired when I click on the *Column's Header*. I'd like an event that only fires when the *button* is clicked... Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use these events but with checking that the **e.Source** (or something similar) is one of the cells you want to be clickable.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN it doesn't look like it since the the header is also a row.

What you can do is to use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex property to determine whether the click occurred in a button cell and not on the column header.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried the example on the link, it works fine when I click on the header, it goes to *return;*. But when I click on a normal row, it gives me this error: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*. I tried this code: *if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex !=
            dataGridView1.Columns["Status Request"].Index) return;*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just need to check if it is NOT a *DataGridViewButtomColumn* and the *.RowIndex*. Like this:

```
if (!(MyDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex != -1)) return;
    {

       //MyCodeHere
    }
```